# Lazy AND operator between functions to long format

Tags: javascript

I am new about javascript so I can not understand this code.

```
markSelected: function (a) {
    a && (array.forEach(query(".menuNode", this.domNode), function (x) { domClass.remove(x, "menuySelectedNode"); }),
       (a = dom.byId("galleryNode_" + a.id)) && domClass.add(a, "menuSelectedNode"));
}
```

I can not write understandable format. I want to separate the following code:

```
(a = dom.byId("galleryNode_" + a.id)) && domClass.add(a, "menuSelectedNode"))
```

like this:

```
markSelected: function (a) {
   if(a){
     // foreach....

     var node = dom.byId("galleryNode_" + a.id);
     if(node){domClass.add(a, "menuSelectedNode")}
   }
}
```

this time, `domClass.add(a,"menuSelectedNode")` didn't work. But in short form working.

Comment: Add check for `a` first (i.e., `if (!a) return;`)

Comment: Yea, you forgot about the `a &&` at the start of the function.

Comment: @Cerbrus that would throw a syntax error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token var`

Comment: @Cerbrus removed. Apparently I was mistaken

Comment: Try `domClass.add(node,"menuSelectedNode")` instead of `domClass.add(a,"menuSelectedNode")`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you check for `a`, first.

```
a && (/*stuff*/)
```

Translates into:

```
if(a){
    /*stuff*/
}
```